# py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound

Tags: 20.04, package-management, python3

I have deleted my python3 because of multiple symlinks issue, and I'm trying to isntall it again on Ubuntu `20.04`, but I'm getting the error:

```
py3compile:183: cannot create directory 
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound...
```

as you can see in the photo blow, the same problem appears while installing any package including `python3-commandnotfound`, can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What command did you try and install with?   Were you using `dpkg` and installing `python3-minimal` first?

Comment: @guiverc `The following packages have unmet dependencies: python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.11.2-1 is installed` I can't remove te wrong version of python3-minmal to install the correct one!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu ?   `python3-minimal (3.11.2-1) ` or https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-minimal is not a Ubuntu package at all.   If you provide additional details; please add them to your question (this is a Q&A site & not a forum; comments are to the *Original Poster* or non-OP Commenter). You also didn't provide command as requested (which is actually key with python3 issues!)

Comment: Can you say more about the steps you took to install it? Including both the command you ran and the errors you are seeing will help the community help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Reinstall the default Python 3 version by running the following commands:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-minimal
   sudo apt install python3-minimal  
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-all  
   sudo apt install python3-all  
   sudo reboot
   ```